# How can I debug my own service on locally

Tags: kubernetes, debugging

My project gets 67 services and they are implemented using Spring Boot and Java. Our project also uses k8s and docker image to deploy them. We got test environment to deploy these services.

As you know, it doesn't have any personal computer that can deploy all services like server - test environment and my question is: if I now debug and write source code for Service A and rest of services still run/deploy on test environment. Do we have any solution for that? I mean it have any request send to our project and it will use instance of service A on my local computer but rest of services still use on test environment?

If you have any advices or recommendation please let me know.

Comment: For unit testing especially, mocks are your friend.  I've been tending to write cross-service calls wrapped in Java interfaces, and then have Spring beans that can inject pure-code mocks in place of the real clients.  Depending on your setup, you may be able to `kubectl port-forward` connections to indiviual services as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I used on one of project to run one service locally and access rest inside Kubernetes cluster, was create VPN connection to the cluster using OpenVPN(with TCP mode) running as Pod.

Each of the service can be simply accessed using full DNS name, for example if service is called `backend` and namespace `develop` you can access it using `backend.develop.svc.cluster.local`.

To make it work you need to set your DNS server on VPN server to `10.96.0.10` also forward all cluster IP through VPN, for example using `route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0`(depends on your Cluster network configuration)

---

Another solution that I found but never used it is [kubevpn](https://github.com/kubenetworks/kubevpn)